# Can I transfer my Thunderbird Lightning Calendar from home computer to my Android phone

Tags: calendar

I use Thunderbird with the Lightning extension on my home computer for email and calendar. Is there a way of transferring just the calendar to my Android phone? It would be so useful when away from home so I can make appointments. The only way to do it now is to print the page or remember!

Answer (score 3):

If you use Google calendar, you can

- Export the calendar from lightning as an .ics file
- Import that .ics file into Google Calendar

Comment: Missed and important step.  To avoid having to do that going forward (ie, automatic syncing), after you import the .ics file you can also add your Google calendar to Lightning, make it the default calendar, and then delete the local only calendar.  This will ensure that all future TBird calendar events go on your Google calendar, which will then be pulled down by your phone calendar app as well.

Comment: Google calendar doesn't just accept any ics from any guy. I tried one from banana soft and it stops with `Error at line 11: String index out of range: 5`. Line 11 is `11 TZOFFSETFROM:0100` (line 4 is `4 PRODID:-//Apple Computer\, Inc//iCal 3.0//EN`).

Comment: @ott: that's obviously a bug; please report it to Google.